# How to keep a air bubble bottom of a water glass?

Tags: experimental-physics, fluid-statics, bubbles

Suppose we have a glass of water. if we make a air bubble bottom of the glass using a straw that will quickly come to the surface because of the pressure ,density difference and the gravity . Assume that the air bubble we are going to make is a pure hydrogen bubble and we have some wired way of making any changes to the atoms in the air bubble . so is there  any way of keeping the air bubble in the bottom of the water by adding some changes to hydrogen atoms in the bubble like excitation ?

adding Oxygen atoms and converting it to water is not acceptable.  if we can match the natural frequencies of both water and hydrogen (resonance frequency of molecules) will that help to keep that in the bottom? (after changes,doesn't matter what happened to the size of the bubble , even it became a dot )

Comment: A sufficently small bubble can stick to the bottom or the sides of the vessel because of _[surface tension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension)_, but the bubble has to form _on_ the surface in the first place, or it won't stick. You can observe the phenomenon if you place a pan of cold water on a stove and slowly heat it. Air that was dissolved in the water will come out of solution, and form tiny bubbles that stick to the bottom of the pan.

Comment: thank you but i want to know some changes is possible within the bubble rather than sticking to the wall or the bottom